# How to I reference the cell above the cell that was passed into my function?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a function in Excel VBA that accepts the value of the cell passed to it as a argument and performs some calculations. I also need the value of the cell right above the one that was passed.

I'd like to avoid having to pass the cell right above as a additional argument. Is there another way to get the value of the cell that is located directly above the cell that was passed as a argument?

Comment: [`Range.Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)? Make sure to test that the cell passed as an argument has a row of 2 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an idea:

```
if my_cell.Row = 1
then MsgBox ("Are you kidding")
else my_cell.Offset(-1,0).go_ahead()
end if
```